# How to get boolean value from application.yml in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have application.yml that looks like this:

```
feature:
  toggles:
    checksLoginAndRegistration: true
```

I am trying to get it in my class with `@Value` annotation, but it's not working.

```
public class UMLUserRepository implements UserRepository {

    @Value("${feature.toggles.checksLoginAndRegistration}")
    private boolean checksLoginAndRegistration;

        private void validateLoginNow(LoginInfo info, User user) {
        checkKnownBlock(info, user.username);
        if(checksLoginAndRegistration){
            try {
                service.validateLogin(user.username);
            } catch (ValidationException alidationException) {
                throw new Exception(user.username);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I debug the code my `checksLoginAndRegistration` variable is set to `false`.

Comment: Are you trying to injecting this value to a spring bean?

Comment: Nope, I am just trying to get it in variable and thats it

Comment: Can you add the code of that class

Comment: It is a huge class so I rather not. Why?

Comment: "This annotation can be used for injecting values into fields in Spring-managed beans, and it can be applied at the field or constructor/method parameter level."

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. I added just part of code where I am actually using it

Comment: Is that was your issue?

Comment: So this is an example of class where I am using it, it supposes to give a true in if statement but is giving back false. And I am not sure why since it is set as true in .yml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comments you have used `@Value` annotation within a simple POJO. Not inside a Spring Bean like `@Component`, `@Service` or `@Configuration`.

You cannot inject a value to a POJO class using `@Value`.

> This annotation can be used for injecting values into fields in Spring-managed beans, and it can be applied at the field or constructor/method parameter level.

But still you get value `false` for `checksLoginAndRegistration` parameter because it is an primitive type which has a default value `false`. If you chaged it to boxed type `Boolean` you can see the value of `checksLoginAndRegistration` is `null`

#### Update

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "feature.toggles")
public class AppConfig {
    private Boolean checksLoginAndRegistration;
}
```

Then update your `UMLUserRepository` class, (We make `checksLoginAndRegistration` is a dependency to `UMLUserRepository` class)

```
public class UMLUserRepository implements UserRepository {
    private final Boolean checksLoginAndRegistration;
 
    public UMLUserRepository(Boolean checksLoginAndRegistration) {
        this.checksLoginAndRegistration = checksLoginAndRegistration;
    }
}
```

This is the class where you crate instance of `UMLUserRepository` class. An it should be a Spring Bean.

```
@Component (or @Service)
public class ClassYouInitatingUMLUserRepository {

    @Autowire
    private AppConfig appConfig;

    public void yourMethod() {
        UMLUserRepository repo = new UMLUserRepository(appConfig.getChecksLoginAndRegistration());
    }
```

I would encourage you to check the possibility to convert `UMLUserRepository` class to a Spring bean. Then this won't be needed.

Comment: Yes, when I would try to change it to `Boolean` it would be null. So to explain why am I doing this code. I want to create feature toggle very simple and say that statement `checksLoginAndRegistration = true` has to be `true` for when I am running in a dev, but when I run it in prod I want it to be `false` , like I want it to not be there in prod. Do you have any advice how to do it with modification of existing code?

Comment: I edited my code more so this class that I have it implements repository. Please take a look.

Comment: We can create `@ConfigurationProperties`  class to extract the required properties from `application.yml` file. Then again that class will be a Spring Bean and still you cannot inject that to your `UMLUserRepository` class. In your  `UMLUserRepository` class you can create a constructor that takes a parameter type of that `@Configuration` class.

Comment: Then when you initialize your `UMLUserRepository` class in your code, pass that bean to the class constructor.

Comment: Can you please show me that example when creating constructor that takes a parameter type of that @Configuration class in UMLUserRepository class?

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was very useful

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it seems like you do everything correctly. I can suggest what can go wrong

- Is it all what file contains?

If not, check is there only one `feature` key or not. If there's another one, remove it.

- Have you added `@Configuration` annotation to your configuration class?

If not, add it.

Comment: Yes, I have check and everything is there. That's why I don't understand.